# Where MySQL crashes are logged on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu

When I log in to my Ubuntu 16.04 installed on some VPS via a web console I periodically see the following message:

```
'Out of memory: Killed process 1190 (mysqld)' on Ubuntu 16.04
```

But it is not clear where is this message in the logs? What command to use to see how many times and when MySQL crashed?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely the "OOM killer". When you have no memory left, Linux kills the biggest users, and on a small server this is likely MySQL (had the same problem on my server). So there is no real problem with MySQL, it is more a general configuration problem.

Use `free` to check your memory usage, if you are regularly under 20% free, you will get in such situations when you have many simultaneous connections. In my case I took advantage of the provider changing the plan and letting me have 1GB for the same price as I paid for 512M.

Answer (score 1):

This message can ve viewed with `dmesg` command.
Another approach can be use the `journalctl` command.

You can check the `/var/log/message` too, but rsyslog have to be installed.

NOTE: you have to be root

You can read the log of the system using the state-of-the-art log navigator called `lnav`.

Install it from .deb package

```bsh
wget --quiet --output-document=- https://github.com/tstack/lnav/releases/download/v0.8.5/lnav_0.8.5_amd64.deb | dpkg --install -
```

Then login as root and run:

```bsh
lnav /var/log
```

From your message, seems that the logging daemon is not active. In order to activate it:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install rsyslog
sudo service rsyslog start
sudo service rsyslog status
```

Now you can view your log using `lnav /var/log`

Comment: Cannot figure out what are the arguments of `dmesg` command? And unfortunately there is no `/var/log/message` file on my machine.

Comment: The command `sudo dmesg | grep -i 'mysql'` does not print anything.

Comment: File ` /var/log/dmesg` exists, but it is empty.

Comment: `rsyslog` was not installed. You can install and reproduce the out-of-memory with `stress` tool

Comment: I have `rsyslog` installed and started.